# The view main.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

Okay so I looked through a few different slack posts on this ValueError, but it seemed most of them had to do with not returning render which it seems like I am doing that correct..?

I am sure it has to do with my if statements, just not sure what exactly or how to set the code up correctly so I can check the form request to the browser.

Edit: Following comments I took the is_valid check out for now just to see if I could get a new error, and it seems I am getting a name error. " name 'name' is not defined "

So it's not able to get the form users input into the api.

`views.py:`

```
from http.client import responses
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SearchUser
from .search import search


def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchUser(request.POST)
        form.cleaned_data["name"]
    else:
            return render(request, "main/home.html", {
                'form': SearchUser(),  # Reference to form
                'userid': search(request),
                # 'mmr':NA,
            })
```

`search.py:`

```
import requests


def search(request):
    data = requests.get(
        f"https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/{name}/NA1?api_key=RGAPI-d1224a2c-9130-45ff-8c05-0656d56d105f")
    return data.json()['puuid']
```

`urls.py:`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name=""),
    #path("", views.search, name=""),
]
```

`home.html:`

```
{% extends 'main/base.html'%}


{% block content %}
    <h2>Valorant Ranked Checker</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit" name="search">
            Get rank
        </button>
    </form>
    <p><strong>{{userid}} - {{mmr}}</strong></p>
{% endblock %}
```

`forms.py:`

```
from django import forms


class SearchUser(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=200)
```

Comment: If `form.is_valid()` holds, your view is *not* returning anything, the same with a GET request.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So should I even check if its valid in my view? What would be the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: @Blue Can you share your `SearchUser` form and model also?

Comment: @SunderamDubey No model, since won't be saving user info in DB right now but will show the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the view requires to return single HttpResponse, outside the conditions.

Try below view:

```py
def home(request):
    user_id = ''
    form = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchUser(request.POST)
        print('form is coming')
        # form.cleaned_data["name"]
        return HttpResponse('<h2> form submitted.</h2>') #just for testing purpose you can remove it.
    else:
        form = SearchUser()
        user_id = search(request)
    return render(request, "main/home.html", {
        'form': form,  # Reference to form
        'userid': user_id,
        # 'mmr':NA,
    })
```

> `Note:` You should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn’t specific to Django; it’s good web development practice in general.

So,

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def home(request):
    user_id = ''
    form = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchUser(request.POST)
        print('form is coming')
        # form.cleaned_data["name"]   
        return redirect('some_path_name')  #Redirection is a good practice.   
    else:
         ...
         ...
```

## Edit:

Try this code:

search.py

```py
import requests

def search(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name', 'novalue')
    if name != 'novalue':
        print('--------------------------------')
        print(name)
        print('--------------------------------')

        data = requests.get(
            f"https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/{name}/NA1?api_key=RGAPI-d801ef44-e952-43b0-9b08-92badc7da82c")
        print(data.url)
        try:

            puuid = data.json()['puuid']

            if puuid:
                print('-------------------this is ppuid-------------')
                print(puuid)
                print('-------------------this is ppuid-------------')
                print(name, 'has come here, means 200')
                return puuid
        except:
            print(name, 'has come here, means not found or forbidden')

            return 'puuid not found'
```

home.html

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html'%}


{% block content %}
    <h2>Valorant Ranked Checker</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit" name="search">
            Get rank
        </button>
    </form>
    {% if userid != "puuid not found" %}
        <p><strong>ppuid found - {{userid}}</strong></p>
    {% else %}
        <p><strong>{{userid}}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from .forms import SearchUser
from .search import search


def home(request):
    user_id = ''
    form = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is coming')
            name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            print(name)
            user_id = search(request)
            return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'form': form, 'userid': user_id})
    else:
        form = SearchUser()
        user_id = search(request)
    return render(request, "main/home.html", {
        'form': form,  # Reference to form
        'userid': user_id,
        # 'mmr':NA,
    })
```