# The view basket.views.basket_add didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

So when previously i tried to add the price, it worked. When I added the quantity of the product something failed. I watched it many times but without luck. If someone can help me I would be grateful.

So that is my the error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgYvs.png)
Then there are my views: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jA8S.png)
The HTML, and jquery/css: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaoXK.png)
and finally my add func: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Hsn.png)

I have to return the quantity with the success console log in the ajax in the chrome console.

I tried to change the data type, adding a more advanced error func to show me more in-depth errors in the browser, refreshing the session, watched all the names that I have to see if I typed some names wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The view main.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749639/the-view-main-views-home-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you are returning JsonResponse from the POST request. For the GET request, you are not producing any response. By default, the request is GET. Most probably you are making a GET request. Just add `return HttpReponse('')`  at the end of the view or make sure you are making a proper POST request.

```
def add_basket(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         # Add In basket
         return JsonResponse(data)
    
    return render(request,"app_name/add_basket.html")
```